# How to get the number of generations of a node?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XML string or file in vb.net. My question is, how do you get the number of generations a node has (going downwards child, grandchild, great grandchild...)?

Here is my code:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(Str)

Dim root As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/ROOT/SUBCATEGORY")

If root.HasChildNodes Then
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To root.ChildNodes.Count - 1
        TextBox1.AppendText(root.ChildNodes(i).Name)
        TextBox1.AppendText(vbTab)
        TextBox1.AppendText(Number Of Generations)
        TextBox1.AppendText(vbNewLine)
    Next (i)
End If
```

Comment: Does this work: `root.SelectSingleNode("max(descendant::*[not(*)]/count(ancestor::*))")`? You could the get the `Depth` property of it.

Comment: @Asad I get the following: XPathException was unhandled `'max(descendant::*[not(*)]/count(ancestor::*))'` has an invalid token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `XmlNodeReader` class has a `Depth` property that can tell you the depth of the current node, like this:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(Str)

Dim deepestNodeLevel As Integer = 0

Using nodeReader As New XmlNodeReader(doc)
    While nodeReader.Read()
        If nodeReader.Depth > deepestNode Then
            deepestNodeLevel = nodeReader.Depth
        End If
    End While
End Using
```

Now after going through the whole XML document you will know the deepest depth (`deepestNodeLevel`) of any element in the structure.

Adapting this to your posted code, you can do this:

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml(Str)

Using nodeReader As New XmlNodeReader(doc)
    While nodeReader.Read()
        TextBox1.AppendText(nodeReader.Name)
        TextBox1.AppendText(vbTab)
        TextBox1.AppendText(nodeReader.Depth.ToString())
        TextBox1.AppendText(vbNewLine)
    End While
End Using
```